# How to turn on Autorization?

Tags: admin-on-rest

"By default, an admin-on-rest app doesn’t require authentication".

I have written an application with AOR and Loopback API, etc, and it works well. Except for one thing, I can't turn on turn on authentication. Any username/password will work, just like in the Demo.

From what I can see all required components load, AuthClient etc., Loopback is configured and is waiting for user authorization requests but never gets any.

I copy/pasted a lot of Demo's parts...

Any hints please?

I use the unchanged authClient from [kimkha aor loopback](https://github.com/kimkha/loopback3-xTotalCount)

```
 import storage from './storage';
export const authClient = (loginApiUrl, noAccessPage = '/login') => {
    return (type, params) => {
        if (type === 'AUTH_LOGIN') {
            const request = new Request(loginApiUrl, {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify(params),
                headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
            });
            return fetch(request)
                .then(response => {
                    if (response.status < 200 || response.status >= 300) {
                        throw new Error(response.statusText);
                    }
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then(({ ttl, ...data }) => {
                    storage.save('lbtoken', data, ttl);
                });
        }
        if (type === 'AUTH_LOGOUT') {
            storage.remove('lbtoken');
            return Promise.resolve();
        }
        if (type === 'AUTH_ERROR') {
            const { status } = params;
            if (status === 401 || status === 403) {
                storage.remove('lbtoken');
                return Promise.reject();
            }
            return Promise.resolve();
        }
        if (type === 'AUTH_CHECK') {
            const token = storage.load('lbtoken');
            if (token && token.id) {
                return Promise.resolve();
            } else {
                storage.remove('lbtoken');
                return Promise.reject({ redirectTo: noAccessPage });
            }
        }
        return Promise.reject('Unkown method');
    };
};
```

Comment: Can you share your authClient ?

Comment: Hi Gildas, Thank you. I added the the authClient code to my question.

Comment: So I guess you never reach the line where you throw an error ?

Comment: No. AUTH_ERROR is never thrown.

Comment: Can you paste the response for a login request which should not have succeeded ?

Comment: There are no login requests when login is pressed. No network traffic at all until the default page opens. The login.js is from the demo. I have tried the most simple login.js as well, but that makes no difference.

Comment: Are you sure you passed the authClient to the Admin component ? Otherwise,I'll need a repository/codepen with the `Admin` component, the `authClient` and eventually the `Login` component if you customized it. Can't really help you with so little info

Comment: Hi Gildas, Well authClient is imported and configured in App.js. But isn't doing much. App.js authClient.js and Login.js on https://github.com/Balipeace/AOR-Mojo

Comment: Can you see the LOGIN action in the redux devtool when you try to login ?

Comment: Yes. '{
  type: 'AOR/USER_LOGIN',
  payload: {
    username: 'donald@duck.com',
    password: 'mini'
  },
  meta: {
    auth: true,
    pathName: '/'
  }
}

Comment: Can you put a running example somewhere ?